# Sending SVN commits to an RSS feed

Tags: svn, rss

So my favourite web tool, [Subtlety](http://subtlety.errtheblog.com), was recently discontinued, which means that I no longer have easy access to the commit logs of various SVN projects that I follow.  Are there any other tools that easily pump out an RSS feed of commits for a public SVN repo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was going to suggest Trac as well, until I realized you probably don't have administrative control over the repositories in question.  Perhaps this apparent solution will work for you?

http://svnfeed.com/

It seems to work well for the one repository I tried it on, and it's surprisingly fast.

Comment: Oh man, this is perfect.  It actually seems to be better than subtlety, because the files changed link to diff messages.  A+++ would ask again.

Comment: The http://svnfeed link no longer seems to work as of 04/09/2012 10:04 (GMT), use this link http://el-tramo.be/software/svnfeed/

Answer (score 2):

[SvnFeed](http://svnfeed.com)

Also check out [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor) for windows, which features really slick diff support

Comment: Huh, CommitMonitor seems a bit more intrusive than I want, and also tied to one machine, but interesting nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried [sventon](http://www.sventon.org) with good results. It's a web based SVN viewer, reasonable in what it does, but provides a good RSS feed at whatever level you want to subscribe to.

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian Fisheye ( http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/ ) allows you to get commit notification on email as well as RSS (and as a bonus, you can select which directory/file to subscribe to, and only get notified of those file/dir changes).

Answer (score 1):

Another tool would be http://sourceforge.net/projects/svn2rss/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).  Besides feeds you can browse the repository and it has a nice Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), though it may be overkill for what you need.  [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/) is also a nice tool for browsing repositories over the web.  Both of these provide RSS feeds for the log.  You can also subscribe to the log for just a particular branch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Sublety as well. It was quite a bummer when it went away. I ended up rolling my own solution. It is .NET based and requires the use of the post-commit hook script. It's free, and I've provided both binaries and source code.

[Subversion C# RSS Feed Hook Script](http://www.systemwidgets.com/Downloads/FreeDownloads/SubversionChooks/tabid/82/Default.aspx)

[Live repository rss feed with nice xsl template](http://www.wheelmud.net/Development/DevelopmentLog/tabid/62/Default.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

There's [subveRSSed](http://www.subversionary.org/projects/subverssed), which you just drop into your post-commit action.