# TFS checkin RSS feed

Tags: version-control, tfs, rss

How can I to generate an RSS feed of Team Foundation Server commit messages?

In Visual Studio's Source Control Explorer, the "View History" option produces a nice GUI view.  Likewise, the command line

```
tf history /recursive /stopafter:40 .
```

produces a nice *GUI* view.  I'd like an RSS feed that would supply the same, or similar, information -- or even a way to wring some text out of TFS that I can reconstitute into RSS.

This is similar to the question, [Sending SVN commits to an RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125028/sending-svn-commits-to-an-rss-feed), but I do have control over the private TFS repository.

Answer (score 4):

One of the links from [Grant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158941/tfs-checkin-rss-feed#159917) seems even better than [the original page](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2005/12/21/506277.asp).  It contains source code for ASPX file that generates an RSS feed of TFS checkins which returns information about the most recent N checkins:

http://blogs.msdn.com/jefflu/archive/2005/07/27/443900.aspx

I haven't tried it out yet, and it doesn't appear to include the checkin comment, which is the most important part from my perspective.

Comment: To anyone coming here, Jeff Lucovsky [updated the code in a newer post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jefflu/archive/2005/09/23/473248.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2005/12/21/506277.aspx