# quickly see latest committed file names in svn

Tags: svn

Does anybody now a quick way to ask svn the list of the top n most recent filenames *added* the last commits?

Answer (score 2):

> svn log {path} -v --limit {number}

More info: [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

If you want only the *added* files you could `grep` them:

> svn log {path} -v -l {number} | grep "^\s+A\s+"

Because the `--limit` parameter only limits the revisions you could use `grep` to count the added files for you:

> svn log {path} -v | grep -m {max_count} "^\s+A\s+"

But be careful! This could take a long time, because all changes are logged to the console. So I think it's better to set a limit for `svn log`.

Another way is to add the `--xml` option and use a XSLT script to parse the added entries.

Comment: Thanks Gadolin. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in this [question about generating an RSS feed from SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125028/sending-svn-commits-to-an-rss-feed)